# HTML 5 video loading very slowly in IE 11

Tags: html, html5-video

I am using html 5 video tags to display a video as my sites desktop hero image. It works without issue in chrome and Fire Fox, loading almost instantly. But in IE 11 and I assume earlier versions, it takes about 10 seconds to load. I am not sure why this would be. mp4 video is 16MB, and the other formats are smaller.

```
<video autoplay loop class="hero-video">           
 <source src="/img/10_Seconds_w_o_Matte.mp4" type="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2" />
 <source src="/img/10_Seconds_w_o_Matte.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
 <source src="/img/10_Seconds_w_o_Matte.webm" type="video/webm" />
 <source src="/img/hero2_img.jpg" />

 Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
 </video>
```

Comment: I think you answered your own question - "mp4 video is 16MB, and the other formats are smaller".

Comment: I believe Chrome loads mp4 though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome removed h264 support several years ago https://blog.chromium.org/2011/01/html-video-codec-support-in-chrome.html

So Chrome and Firefox are coming into your code and skipping past the mp4 and loading the smaller files while IE 11 only supports mp4 so it must load the larger video.

Your problem is with the size of your mp4.  Guessing by the name of the files it looks like you might be able to do some funny business with a animated gif instead of the video for IE if you'd like it to load faster. Just a suggestion. Unfortunately if that is the smallest the mp4 will get and you must use a video file then you are kind of stuck with it loading slow in IE.

Comment: Chrome announced that they will remove H.264 support but that has not been done, neither has Firefox. Codec preference might play a role here, but H.264 is still supported.